Express $E[T \mid T\ge t, X]$ using conditional cdf $F(t\mid X)$.
Given $T$ is a nonnegative random variable and $X$ can be any arbitrary random variable. I want to rewrite $E[T \mid T\ge t, X]$ in terms of the conditional cumulative distribution of $T$, denoted as $F(\cdot\mid X)$.
Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align*}
E[T \mid T\ge t, X=x] &=  \frac{E[T \cdot I(T\ge t) \mid X=x]}{P(T\ge t \mid X)}\\
&= \frac{\int_0^\infty v \cdot I(v \ge t) \,dF(v\mid X=x)}{1-F(t\mid X=x)}\\
&= \frac{\int_t^\infty v \,dF(v\mid X=x)}{1-F(t\mid X=x)}\\
\end{align*}
I'm not confident about the first equality, which is based on a result given in my class:

Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $X\in L^1((\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P))$. Let $\mathcal{G}= \sigma(\rho)$, here $\rho = \{B_1,...,B_n\} \subset \mathcal{F}$ is a finite partition of $\Omega$. Assuming $P(B_k)>0$, then $$E[X\mid B_k ] =\frac{E[X;B_k]}{P(B_k)} = \frac{\int_{\omega\in B_k}X(\omega)P(d\omega)}{\int_{\omega\in B_k}P(d\omega)}.$$

I understand that conditioning on the event $\{\omega: T(\omega)\ge t\}$ is equivalent as conditioning on the indicator $I(T\ge t)$, but is it correct that I can just move the indicator out of the conditioning like the result given in the class? I'm in doubt because 1) $T$ is continuous nonnegative random variable, so I'm not working with finite partition anymore 2) I have the condition on $X$.

${T\geq t}$ and ${T<t}$ still form a finite partition of $\Omega$ regardless of whether $T$ is continuous or not. The expression you have derived is correct.

But do note that conditioning on the event ${\omega:T(\omega)\geq t}$ does not make sense in rigorous measure theoratic terms. Only conditioning on $I(T\geq t)$, in the sense that you are conditioning on the sigma algebra generated by $I(T\geq t)$. In short, $E(X|B_{k})$ is just a notation meaning $\frac{\int_{B_{k}}X dP}{P(B_{k})}$. In reality, the only conditional expectation is $E(X|\sigma(\rho))=\sum_{k=1}^{n} E(X|B_{k}) I(B_{k})$ . When one says $E(X|B_{k})$ what one means is the value of $E(X|\sigma(\rho))$ under the assumption $I(B_{k})=1$. (in words you say "given $B_{k}$ is true")
